# How to skip missing NaN values in python while also replacing them?

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I want to be able to run numpy commands on a list that maintains NaN values. Basically, I want to do linear regression on two list variables. One variable contains NaN's and so I can't do linear regression on it. But, if I delete the NaN value then the size of my list does not match the size of the non-NaN containing list. For example,

`x = [1,2,3,4,5,NaN]`
If I delete the NaN value then the size of `x` becomes 5
`y = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`
The size of `y` is 6

(x,y) = (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5), (NaN, 6)

I want my linear regression to skip the data point (NaN, 6)

How can I do this?

Comment: a = np.array([(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5), (np.nan, 6)]) then a[~np.any(np.isnan(a), axis=1)]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a proper answer that handles NaN values along with strings.

```
def skipNaN(x, y):
    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)

    condition1 = np.array([isNumber(i) and isNumber(j) for i,j in zip(x,y)])

    x = x[condition1].astype('float64')
    y = y[condition1].astype('float64')

    condition2 = ~np.isnan(x)
    x = x[condition2].astype('float64')
    y = y[condition2].astype('float64')

    return[x,y]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter **both** arrays by the condition, not only one of them.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,np.NaN,4,5,np.NaN])
y = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

condition = ~np.isnan(x)
xp = x[condition]
yp = y[condition]

print(xp)
print(yp)
```

So both arrays print as `[1 2 4 5]`.

Comment: This won't work if there is a string in the array. For example, what if x is `np.array([1,2,np.NaN,4,5,'Hello World'])`. This snippet of code won't be able to remove the string. How would I be able to solve this for strings as well?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37996471/element-wise-test-of-numpy-array-is-numeric)